# How to plot line plot with seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a sample data frame shown below. I want to plot each column against the data frame index.

```
x1 = pd.DataFrame()
x1['x25'] = df['X'][0:45].reset_index(drop=True)
x1['x50'] = df['X'][90:135].reset_index(drop=True)
x1['x75'] = df['X'][180:225].reset_index(drop=True)
x1['x100'] = df['X'][270:315].reset_index(drop=True)
x1['x125'] = df['X'][360:405].reset_index(drop=True)
```

using `x1.head()` the output is shown below.

```
    x25      x50      x75    x100   x125
0   22732   22852   22997   23151   23253
1   22732   22853   22995   23153   23254
2   22733   22851   22997   23153   23254
3   22731   22851   22995   23150   23255
4   22730   22851   22997   23152   23254
```

I checked the output of each column, they are all equal.

```
print(len(x1.index), len(x1['x25']), len(x1['x50']), len(x1['x75']), len(x1['x100']), len(x1['x125']))
```

45 45 45 45 45 45

I am trying to plot with the command below, but i am getting The error message ValueError: arrays must all be same length

```
sns.lineplot( x1, x1.index, ['x25','x50','x75','x100','x125'])
```

could somebody please let me know, what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) on how to use `lineplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling `lineplot` multiple times, passing in object such as pandas series to named arguments:

```
sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1['x25'])
sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1['x50'])
sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1['x75'])
sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1['x100'])
sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1['x125'])
```

Or in loop:

```
for i in  ['x25','x50','x75','x100','x125']:
   sns.lineplot(x=x1.index, y=x1[i])
```

[image: Multiple Line Plots Output]

---

However, consider using a single data frame and hence single `lineplot` call by melting your wide data to long and rendering your index as a column. Then call `lineplot` with *hue* for automatic legend:

```
# CREATE NEW COLUMN NAMED index
x1 = x1.reset_index()

# MELT DATA
mdf = x1.melt(id_vars='index')

# PLOT LINE WITH data AND hue ARGUMENTS
sns.lineplot(x='index', y='value', data=mdf, hue='variable')
```

[image: Single Data Frame Plot]

---

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.uniform(2000, 5000, 500)})

x1 = pd.DataFrame({'x25': df['X'][0:45].reset_index(drop=True),
                   'x50': df['X'][90:135].reset_index(drop=True),
                   'x75': df['X'][180:225].reset_index(drop=True),
                   'x100': df['X'][270:315].reset_index(drop=True),
                   'x125': df['X'][360:405].reset_index(drop=True)})
```